# setting android SDK for MonoDevelop on apple

Tags: android, android-emulator, monodevelop, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run MonoDevelop on apple. I have instaled all the necessary SDK in AVD manager and i can run the simulator. I already setup in MonoDevelop->Preferences->SDK Location->Android SDK to /Developer/SDKs/android-sdk-macosx where i unpack the SDK packed from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. When i try simple Hellou word demo run i get error :"The targetted Android api level cannot be found, please use the Android AVD manager to install the platforms you're targetting".

Where i can find which api lvl I'm targetting? I'm trying to run on api lvl 14.

Comment: At last i found it. I have to set the project options where is located target framework. It should correspond with the Android emulator version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found it. I have to set the project options where is located target framework. It should correspond with the Android emulator version.